# Azure resource ID reported depending on consumed volumes

Tags: azure, resources, azure-api-management, usage-statistics

guys, couldn't find similar question, so asking here.
We have a client to Microsoft REST API, and we receive consumed usage normally for multiple subscriptions. 
But there's a problematic point.
There are some resource types, which are billed depending on the consumed volume. Each of these has got it's own resource ID. For example for BLOB storage there're at least 3 different IDs depending on the consumed amount (which I suspect, should be billed differently).
The question is - am I right presuming, that when end user (our customer) will exceed amount of resources allocated for a particular usage resource ID, next report will contain different resource ID for the same, well, resource? 
Here's the REST response i'm talking about:

```
{
        "usageStartTime": "2017-06-07T17:00:00-07:00",
        "usageEndTime": "2017-06-08T17:00:00-07:00",
        "resource": {
            "id": "**8767aeb3-6909-4db2-9927-3f51e9a9085e**", //I'm talking about this one
            "name": "Storage Admin",
            "category": "Storage",
            "subcategory": "Block Blob",
            "region": "Azure Stack" 
        },
        "quantity": 0.217790327034891,
        "unit": "1 GB/Hr",
        "infoFields": {},
        "instanceData": {
            "resourceUri": "/subscriptions/ab7e2384-eeee-489a-a14f-1eb41ddd261d/resourcegroups/system.local/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageaccounts/srphealthaccount", 
            "location": "azurestack",
            "partNumber": "",
            "orderNumber": "",
            "additionalInfo": { 
                "azureStack.MeterId": "09F8879E-87E9-4305-A572-4B7BE209F857", 
                "azureStack.SubscriptionId": "dbd1aa30-e40d-4436-b465-3a8bc11df027", 
                "azureStack.Location": "local", 
                "azureStack.EventDateTime": "06/05/2017 06:00:00"
            }
        "attributes": {
            "objectType": "AzureUtilizationRecord"
        }
    }
```